# Ultimo elemento RecyclerView se muestra cortado - Android

Tags: android, recyclerview

Hola comunidad StackOverflow en español tengo un problema el ultimo elemento "Otro" de mi RecyclerView se muestra cortado como aquí en la siguiente imagen el detalle de origen esta cortado no se muestra a la totalidad. Mi objetivo es que se muestre el TextView "Indicanos la raza de tu perro" y el RecyclerView en una sola pantalla y que TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS DEL RECYCLERVIEW se muestren COMPLETOS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código main activity que tiene un TextView y un RecyclerView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el item_perros que consta de un TextView, un View, RelativeLayout que adentro tiene un EditText y un imageView que es el boton de continuar.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
        <data>
    
        </data>
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/perroNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Retiro de Fondos de cuenta de Ahorros, Corriente" />
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#0F000000"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/perroNombre"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlReason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_detalle_origen"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/reasons"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent_total"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/enviar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_rectangle_667"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rlReason"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                ></ImageView>
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

El problema se soluciona poniendo match_parent en android:layout_width y en android:layout_height en el RecyclerView pero el TextView "Indicanos la raza de tu perro" se ve sobrescrito por el RecyclerView miren la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código de mi proyecto: https://github.com/Miguel546/Perros

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre es bueno, de ser posible, enlazar los 4 lados de una View dentro del `ConstraintLayout`.

En tu `RecyclerView` cambia esta línea

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Y añade esta

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: Gracias! Si me funcionó.